# Public ip on android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, port

I am trying to receive a string data, sent from a remote server by TCP.

I've opened a certain port in my android device ​and I need to access it from that remote server (not the same network).

Yet the IP address of the Android is BLOCKED for remote access, so there is no possibility to transfer any data​ using sockets.
​ 
​So my question is whether it's possible to make the Android IP become public/accessible ​and how can it be done.

Or maybe there is a completely different way to receive that string data.

Comment: depends on your network provider. most likely you can only start a listening server in WIFI.
If you want to receive data, why don't you just connect to the remote server? You had to send your ip-adress to the remote server anyway. So let your android App be a client an connect to your server which gives you the data you need.

Comment: Yes, your Android app should be a client that connects to the remote machine, not a listening server that the remote machine connects to.